# Remove word inside tuple that only appear once across dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a set of data with multiple rows (>1000) containing tuples of words. I wanted to remove words inside the tuple that only appear once across all rows. Here is an example of the data...

```
        before_cleaning    after_cleaning
0                [cool]            [cool]
1            [gooooood]                []
2  [we, love, it, cool]  [love, it, cool]
3            [love, it]        [love, it]
```

Column *before_cleaning* is the initial data, and column *after_cleaning* is what I expect the data to look like after the removal. As you can see in the example, "gooooood" and "we" is removed as the words only appear once across row 0 until row 3.

Comment: can you provide example code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). [Why not upload images of code on SO  ...?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).  [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755).

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

keep = {k for k,v in Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['before_cleaning'])).items()
        if v>1}
# {'cool', 'it', 'love'}

df['after_cleaning'] = [[x for x in l if x in keep]
                        for l in df['before_cleaning']]
```

Output:

```
        before_cleaning    after_cleaning
0                [cool]            [cool]
1                [good]                []
2  [we, love, it, cool]  [love, it, cool]
3            [love, it]        [love, it]
```

Pandas alternative to create the `set`:

```
keep = set(df['before_cleaning'].explode().value_counts().loc[lambda x: x>1].index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use lambda fun, and inside you can loop over each row list and check if count is more than 1 or not.

Code;

```
df['after'] = df['before'].apply(lambda row: [i for i in row if sum(list(df['before']),[]).count(i)>1])
```